# Lookup field not showing search results on Salesforce mobile app

Tags: lookup, search, salesforce-mobile-app

I am having a weird problem with a lookup field on Salesforce mobile app.
I have created a lookup field from account object to a custom object to lookup records. The field is working fine like returning search results when searched for a string on web browser however on Salesforce mobile app the field is not returning results. I've checked this on both android and iOS apps. Anybody else facing the same issue or if you can help me with anything that I'm missing any configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.    This is a feature that is not yet delivered by Salesforce yet for   
      Salesforce1 mobile app.
2.    Out of the box feature for lookup search on Salesforce mobile app is to search 
      only on the record name field and it will only display the record name column.
3.    The only workaround for this is through steps. 
     -The object name should not be an auto number. 
     -Need automation to populate the object name with relevant field data. This helps 
      searching the string and it gives desired results.
```